Solving transcendental equations involving Bessel functions
I am unable to solve an equation of type that explicitly involves a Bessel function in it. I want to extract the value of $t$ from this equation.
Whenever I try Solve, Mathematica redirects me to use Reduce, but even Reduce didn't help.
Here is my code:
(-k t BesselJ[ 1, k t] + 3 BesselJ[ 2, k t])/(k t^2) == 0

Solve[(-k t BesselJ[ 1, k t] + 3 BesselJ[ 2, k t])/(k t^2) == 0, t]

When using this, the following message occurs:

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods
available to Solve. Try Reduce or FindInstance instead.


Can you assist me in solving this equation?

It may not help you but you might get a little insight. Assume k t^2!=0 Multiply both sides by that. Replace k t by u and then Plot[-u BesselJ[1,u]+3 BesselJ[2,u],{u,-40,40}] and you can see how the solutions behave.

This kind equation can be computed only numerically. Use: FindRoot or NSolve. Code: k = 1; NSolve[(-k t BesselJ[1, k t] + 3 BesselJ[2, k t])/(k t^2) ==     0 && -10 < t < 10, t, Reals] works fine.

It seems you are searching only for real solutions. In the complex case our method would be more involved, however basically it should work similarily.
Parameter $k$ appears in our equation as a scalling constant and it can be eliminated by dividing the left hand side of the equation by $k$.  Now  we set $z = k\;t$ and defining
f[z_]:= -z BesselJ[1, z] + 3 BesselJ[2, z]

our original equation becomes $\frac{f(z)}{z^2}=0$.
We can observe that $z=0$ is not a solution:
Limit[ f[z]/z^2, z -> 0]


 -1/8


Moreover the value of the LHS remains the same by changing $z \to -z$
FullSimplify[ f[z] == f[-z]]


  True


We have demonstrated that the original equation is equivalent to $f(z)=0$ for $z>0$ and for $z<0$ we have $f(z)=f(-z)$.
Usually it is helpful to take a look how the given function behaves
Plot[ f[z]/z^2, {z, -30, 30}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All]

Knowing behaviour of the Bessel functions we expect there are infinitely many solutions, which are symmetric with respect to $z=0$. Now we can look for positive solutions in a bouded domain:
sls = SolveValues[ f[z] == 0 && 1 < z < 30, z] // Quiet


These are symbolic solutions and they can be processed symbolically (see e.g. How do I work with Root objects?).
pts = {sls, ConstantArray[0, 9]} // Transpose;
Plot[{ f[z]/(z^2), Re@BesselY[2, z]}, {z, -30, 30},
  PlotStyle -> Thick, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts],
    Point[-pts]}, PlotRange -> 0.24, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


Taking into account the following identity
Entity["MathematicalFunction", "BesselJ"]["AlternativeRepresentations"][[4]]

which in our case reads $\;J_1(z) Y_2(z)-J_2(z) Y_1(z)=-\frac{2}{\pi  z}\;$ i.e.
FullSimplify[ BesselJ[1, z] BesselY[2, z] - BesselJ[2, z] BesselY[1, z]]


-(2/(Pi z))


as well as the original equation we can see that $k$-th solution tends to BesselYZero[2, k] as $k \to \infty$. We can see on the plot that convergence is quite fast. For large $k$ solutions are approximately equal to $k$-th zeros of the Bessel function $Y_2(z)$, e.g.
NSolveValues[f[z] == 0 && (195 < z < 200 || 9993 < z < 10000), z]


{195.547, 198.689, 9994.19, 9997.33}


BesselYZero[ 2, {62, 63, 3181, 3182}] // N


{195.555, 198.696, 9994.19, 9997.33}



This is not really adding much more than @Artes already found, but we can see asymptotically as $z \to \infty$, some of the roots should be close to $z = \pi  n+\frac{\pi }{4}$ for positive integer $n$ (I don't know if these are the $n$th roots, they could just be one family of roots).
We start by using the 6th alternative representation of BesselJ
altRep0 = 
  Entity["MathematicalFunction", "BesselJ"][
    "AlternativeRepresentations"][[6]]




In our case v is greater than 0 so we can ignore the conditionals on it
altRep[v_, z_] := Activate@altRep0[v, z][[1, 2]] // Evaluate


(2^-v z^v Hypergeometric0F1[1 + v, -(z^2/4)])/Gamma[1 + v]

Now we replace the new representation in our LHS:
LHS[z_] := (-z BesselJ[1, z] + 3 BesselJ[2, z])/z^2

newExpr[z_] := 
 Simplify[ReplaceAll[LHS[z], BesselJ[v_, z] -> altRep[v, z]], z > 0] //
   Evaluate


1/8 (-4 Hypergeometric0F1[2, -(z^2/4)] +  3 Hypergeometric0F1[3, -(z^2/4)])

And take the first order series expansion at infinity
ser1 = Series[newExpr[z], {z, Infinity, 1}] // Normal


(Sqrt[2/π] Cos[π/4 + z])/z^(3/2)

Which will be zero when Cos[π/4 + z] ==0 $\implies$ z == π/4 + n π for integer n.
Plotting the asymptotic root locations against the LHS shows that the root locations appear to get better as z grows:
nMax = 1000;
zZeros[n_] := \[Pi]/4 + n* \[Pi];
zAsymPts = Table[{zZeros[n], LHS[zZeros[n]]}, {n, nMax}];
lp = ListPlot[zAsymPts, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> {z == zZeros[n]}];
p = Plot[LHS[z], {z, zZeros[0], zZeros[nMax]}, PlotStyle -> Thin];
Show[p, lp, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"z", LHS[z]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]



